# Unable to receive v3 traps/informs with SharpSNMP

Tags: snmp, sharp-snmp, snmp-trap

Using the snmptrapd example I was able to receive v1 traps and v2 traps/informs easily. However, with v3 I am unable to receive traps. I am using AES128 and SHA1 for Privacy and Authentication.

When I "wireshark" port 162 I see "encryptedPDU: privKey unknown" coming from the device I am attempting to receive traps from. It is using NET-SNMP if that helps.

I was able to implement applications using SharpSNMP for gets and sets with no problem. What am I missing here?

Code snippet below:

Note: engine.Start() is called form the instantiating class.

```
        registry = new UserRegistry();
        var authProvider = new SHA1AuthenticationProvider(new OctetString("authsecret"));
        var privacyProvider = new AESPrivacyProvider(new OctetString("privsecret"), authProvider);

        registry.Add(new OctetString("informuser"), privacyProvider);
        registry.Add(new OctetString("trapuser"), privacyProvider);

        TrapV1Handler = new TrapV1MessageHandler();
        TrapV1Handler.MessageReceived += WatcherTrapV1Received;
        v1Mapping = new HandlerMapping("v1", "TRAPV1", TrapV1Handler);

        TrapV2Handler = new TrapV2MessageHandler();
        TrapV2Handler.MessageReceived += WatcherTrapV2Received;
        v2Mapping = new HandlerMapping("v2,v3", "TRAPV2", TrapV2Handler);

        InformHandler = new InformRequestMessageHandler();
        InformHandler.MessageReceived += WatcherInformRequestReceived;
        informMapping = new HandlerMapping("v2,v3", "INFORM", InformHandler);

        store = new ObjectStore();
        var v1 = new Version1MembershipProvider(new OctetString("public"), new OctetString("public"));
        var v2 = new Version2MembershipProvider(new OctetString("public"), new OctetString("public"));
        var v3 = new Version3MembershipProvider();
        var membership = new ComposedMembershipProvider(new IMembershipProvider[] {v1, v2, v3});
        var handlerFactory = new MessageHandlerFactory(new[] {v1Mapping, v2Mapping, informMapping});

        var pipelineFactory = new SnmpApplicationFactory(store, membership, handlerFactory);
        engine = new SnmpEngine(pipelineFactory, new Listener { Users = registry }, new EngineGroup());
        engine.Listener.AddBinding(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 162));
        engine.ExceptionRaised += this.DoSomething;
    }

    private void DoSomething(object sender, ExceptionRaisedEventArgs args)
    {
        // never gets here
    }

    private void WatcherInformRequestReceived(object sender, InformRequestMessageReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        // or here for v3 (works fine for v2)
    }

    private void WatcherTrapV2Received(object sender, TrapV2MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        // or here for v3 (works fine for v2)
    }

    private void WatcherTrapV1Received(object sender, TrapV1MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        // works fine
    }
```

Comment: INFORM v3 is fully supported, while TRAP v3 requires some changes in the authentication provider, https://github.com/lextm/sharpsnmplib/commit/c55d7a46eec74bf78182b8085af7f6e6317374e0

Comment: Thanks Lex, is this in an updated library version or should I pull the changes from Git and rebuild?

Comment: You don't need the latest if you are not using TRAP v2 in SNMP v3, for INFORM v2 is fully supported. The change in snmpsendtrap is meant to demonstrate how to send those messages out. If you do need TRAP v2, you can directly modify 8.5's code base. The master is for vNext currently and not production ready.